# install missing external packages automatically from within emacs

Tags: subprocess

I have some snippets in my config, that depend on external tools. For example I use `xmodmap` at startup.

```
(if (eq window-system 'x)
    (if (file-exists-p "/usr/bin/xmodmap")
        (shell-command "xmodmap -e 'clear Lock' -e 'keycode 66 = F13'")))
```

Is it possible to install xmodmap automatically if it isn't installed ?

**EDIT**

@Ehvince When I install xmodmap in the else clause, the xmodmap command won't be executed. I think I need some piece of code that waits for the subprocess to be finished before executing the xmodmap command ?
Another problem is, I can't install a package when I start emacs without sudo. So I need a password prompt, I guess.

Comment: what do you mean ? Looks like you did all the job with the `if`, didn't you ? You could install xmodmap in the else clause.

Comment: You can start a process synchroneous via `call-process-region`. Emacs then waits until the process is finished before executing the next statement. The password can be read from stdin by `sudo`. The password input is read with `read-passwd`. Overall you have something like: `(with-temp-buffer (insert (read-password) "\n") (call-process-region (point-min) (point-max) "sudo" t nil "-S" "aptitude" "install" "xmodmap")`. (Note, that this is untested.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Tobias and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2473152/5883049) I was able to find a solution.

```
(when (eq window-system 'x)
  (unless (file-exists-p "/usr/bin/xmodmap")
    (call-process-shell-command (concat "echo " (shell-quote-argument (read-passwd "Password: "))
                                        " | sudo -S apt-get install xmodmap")))
  (shell-command "xmodmap -e 'clear Lock' -e 'keycode 66 = F13'"))
```

`call-process-shell-command` executes aptitude synchronously in a separate process.

Comment: Please accept your own answer to mark this question answered. Thanks in advance,